# nmap command failing with error for ssl-enum-ciphers

Tags: linux, nmap

I want to see all ciphers on my SLES Linux system.

For this fire the below command which returns me error.

```
nmap --script ssl-enum-ciphers -p 630 168.43.136.838

Starting Nmap 4.75 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2016-10-06 13:23 IST
SCRIPT ENGINE: error while initializing script rules:
No such category, file or directory: 'ssl-enum-ciphers'
stack traceback:
        [C]: ?

SCRIPT ENGINE: Aborting script scan.
```

What is missing here and how to get the nmap command working?

Comment: If I copy the .nds file in scripts directory and tn fire the above command it gives me error:

Starting Nmap 4.75 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2016-10-06 13:47 IST
SCRIPT ENGINE: './ssl-enum-ciphers.nse' could not be compiled.
Interesting ports on my-linux-box (168.43.136.838):
PORT    STATE SERVICE
630/tcp open  ldapssl

Answer (score 2):

Nmap 4.75 was released 8 years ago, and predates the `ssl-enum-ciphers` script by 2 years. The script has undergone a lot of changes and improvements since then, too, as well as 2 language version changes (Lua 5.1 to 5.3). You need to download and install the [latest release of Nmap](https://nmap.org/download.html) to use this script to its full potential.